# 'adb devices' showing dummy device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have been facing this problem for quite sometime now. Running 'adb devices' shows me an additional dummy device although its named as emulator-5554. FYI, I don't have any emulator running as well.

**adb devices**

> List of devices attached:
>   xxxxxxx device (Actual device)
>   emulator-5554   device (Dummy thingy shown as device).

How do I clean up this mess?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have figured out the issue. I had installed [Bluestacks for Mac](http://bluestacks.com/bstks_mac.html) for trying out Android apps on Mac. This was running an emulator with a different name.

Figured it out by taking a screenshot of the emulator and it showed the launch screen of Bluestacks. Uninstalled Bluestacks and all is well now.

Comment: Is there a way without uninstalling bluestacks? Probably if you kill the Bluestacks Service process? I am asking because I an unable to view logs in eclipse due to the presence of 2 devices.

Answer (score 23):

Same problem for me but I don't see any Bluestacks service in my services list. after 
`adb devices` shows emulators I didn't have, I usually just type the command

```
adb kill-server
```

and running the

```
adb devices
```

once more shows only the devices that are connected.

Comment: This is just a workaround. I wonder what could be the cause of this, so it's easier to prevent it from happening at the first place.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. I did this and now everything is ok

1. click Windows+R
2. type `services.msc`
3. stop `BlueStacks Android Service`

Comment: For the lazy: Win+R: `sc stop BstHdAndroidSvc`. You can then pick it from Run history later.

Answer (score 4):

the adb server is scanning for emulators on all even local ports from 5555 to 5555+128 (5683). If you have a custom service which use one of these ports... You are stuck with the "adb -d command" requirement

Answer (score 1):

pls check in task manager whether **emulator-arm.exe** is running. If so, try stopping both **adb.exe** and **emulator-arm.exe**

Comment: Isn't that the daemon which is supposed to be running??

Comment: No, emulator is not running. adb daemon is running though. Btw, I am on Mac.

Comment: I guess you know those running tasks could be seen by this. Applications > Utilities > Activity Monitor.

Comment: Yes, I know. It happens even after restarting it. Feel that the issue might be with some stale file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and non of these answers helped. So I figured out that my system didn't shut down properly and that's the reason I have a dummy emulator-5554. The solution was to create a new emulator with a name then launch it? While it's launching kill the server using cmd until when the emulator powers on and you can see its name under Devices in DDMS. After this shut the emulator...emulator-5554 is gone, Now you can start Bluestacks and connect

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, and that due to BlueStacks too. In case you have Windows and you don't want to remove it, then you can stop its service "BlueStacks Android Service."

To do that click Windows+R, type services.msc then stop "BlueStacks Android Service"

Reference:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2612389

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse emulator NOT BlueStacks:**

In the case of the eclipse emulator running in the background and you don't know how to close it, just go to devices tab and choose the dropdown menu on the right, then `Reset adb`. OR, just reset the adb using adb console.

Answer (score 0):

Just open task manager and end task bluestacks

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same problem.Here is my answer to solve this problem.
in Windows system.

1.in cmd terminal,usr cmd *netstat -aon|findstr "5555"*

2.use cmd *tasklist|find "PID"*,the PID para should be a process number which is the result of the first step .

3.changed the Port No. to other ,which should not be "5555"

That's done.

Answer (score 0):

After trying:

1. adb kill-server
2. stopping adb.exe in task manager
3. adb usb
4. and a few other stuff I can't even remember. . .

I restarted my computer and the dummy-device was gone!